# defining my own new operator

Tags: c++, embedded, new-operator

------------------------------------------1------------------------------------------

I'm compiling a program for an ARM running embedded Linux. I originally wrote the program to be a c++ program, so there's some `operator new` and `operator delete`s in the code. Now, to compile stuff with `operator new`s and `operator delete`s for an typical PC platform, I need to specify a particular argument to the linker (-lstdc++). I don't know exactly what this does.

Now, if I attempt to use this linker option with my ARM cross compiler, I link correctly, but I fail at run time with this message:

> Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-deps.c: 622: _dl_map_object_deps: Assertion `nlist > 1' failed!

And if I omit the link option, I run fine. This looks like an assert failure, but that's as far as I'd be willing to venture a guess. Can anyone shed some light on this error or its' likely cause?

-----------------------------------------------2------------------------------------

I decided to omit the the (-lstdc++) option, and replace all my class pointers to pointers to variable instances on the stack. This works, but it's obviously sloppy, and since this is supposed to be an example for students, I want it clean. a clean way to do it would be to create my own `operator new` and `operator delete`... but it is not obvious how I would actually use the self-defined operators.

Take as example, `someClass * foo = new someClass(arg);` This is three(?) steps.

1. calling operator new. allocates some memory for the new class instance.
2. calling class constructor.
3. putting the class instance into the memory location created by operator new

I don't know the order of these steps. I don't know how to call a class constructor independently of creating a new variable of that type on the stack. And I don't know how to put the new class variable into the heap from wherever it starts.

Comment: -lstdc++ indicates to the linker that the application needs to link against whatever the appropriate installed version of libstdc++ is for your environment.

Answer (score 1):

First, a correction.  Your creation statement above is two steps, not three; the class constructor is applied directly to the allocated memory region to turn it from 'random memory' into the object instance.  Otherwise right, though.

Overloading operator new is relatively straightforward.  You don't have to invoke the class constructor in operator new; the language handles those steps separately.  Operator new() is essentially just C++'s version of malloc():

```
void *operator new(std::size_t sz) {
    void *out = ::malloc(sz);
    if (!out) throw new std::bad_alloc();
    return out;
}
```

The above basically mimics the real operator new.  You would need to tweak this to do whatever special operations you need to make your code ARM-capable.  There's some magic in here though, so watch out.  After operator new() concludes, the language invokes your class constructor, which is free to except.  If it does, C++ is required to free the memory allocated by operator new() (since you the programmer don't have a reference to it and therefore can't free it yourself).  Thus, C++ will magically trigger operator delete() in this eventuality... but only if it can find a perfectly matched version.

TL;DR: If you overload operator new(), always also overload operator delete() and make sure they match in signature, scope, etc.